# NodeJS not showing which file the actual error came from

Tags: node.js

I am running into an issue where there is an error in my app and all `Node` tells me is a line number from the `dist` copy of the app.

```
TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at keys (<anonymous>)
    at /Users/MyApp/dist/server.js:346:31
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at /Users/MyApp/dist/server.js:336:46
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at step (/Users/MyApp/node_modules/babel-runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:17:30)
    at /Users/MyApp/node_modules/babel-runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:28:13
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

so how do I know the actual line number and filename where the error was generated instead of pointing me to the `dist` version of the `server.js` file which is not very useful. I have a file called `process.js` and I am sure this is where the error is being generated but the logs don't tell me anything about this file.

Comment: Why are you sure? What's in `dist/server.js` on line 346?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans line 346 is actually a closing brace `}` and beneath that line is this `(0, _keys2.default)(myDict.values).forEach(function (s) {` and hence confusing me to see where the actual error might be.

Comment: That sounds like bundled/packaged code. Is it? If so, did you remember to tell your bundler/packer to include source maps, so that Node can actually tell you which original file/line things went wrong in?

Comment: yes, I am using webpack for it

Comment: then you probably want to include the `devtool` (worst name) option, and see if that gives you some better insight: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/